# Replicating "Guided Access" features from iOS on Android

Tags: buttons, touch

[Guided Access](http://www.howtogeek.com/177366/how-to-lock-down-your-ipad-or-iphone-for-kids/) is an excellent set of features for the iPhone that allows one to restrict or block inputs to the device.  How can I replicate this behavior with my Android phone?

The features the I am most interested in
(so that I can restrict access to my phone when my children are using it) are:

- ability to disable all hard buttons (power, volume up/down, back, home, the button that display open tasks, etc.), and
- ability to disable all touch events.

Of course, such an app must also provide a way to re-enable these inputs again using one of them (or said another way, to disable the restrictions).  For example, to disable guided access on the iPhone, one triple-clicks the home button.

Comment: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uDevel.BabyTouch. Not tested though.

Comment: @IvanChau Sure. This is the best one that I have found, but it doesn't have the ability to disable hardware buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop includes a feature called 'screen pinning', where you can lock access to only a specific app; from the app you want to lock to, tap the Recents/Overview button, tap the light teal icon in the bottom-right of the card and follow the instructions onscreen.

Comment: What about the ability to disable hardware buttons?